# Divisibility of a non invertible element in an integral domain

Tags: divisibility, unique-factorization-domains

Let $A$ be a [Unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).

I want to prove :

> Every non-invertible element of $A$ is divisible by at least one irreducible element.

My reason to believe that is because if $x$ is non invertible, either one can write $x=ab$ where $a$ is invertible (in that case $x$ is divisible by a *smaller* non-inverible $b$) , either one cannot write $x=ab$ and $x$ is itself irreducible.

There may be a recursion saying that, getting smaller and smaller non-invertibles, we end up with an irreducible.

Anyway. How to prove the statement ? Since I'm not fluent in algebra, I'd need a link with a detailed proof, including intermediate lemmas and definitions.

Comment: Isn't this trivial? If $A$ is a UFD, then every nonzero nonunit is a product of irreducible elements, so is divisible by at least one irreducible element? I guess like Bill said below, things are different if your definition of UFD is different. What is your definition of UFD?

Comment: The proof depends crucially on your *definition* of a UFD (of which there are many). Please state it explicitly.

Comment: @morrowmh. You are perfectly right. I'm soooo bad in algebra, and soooo French speaking that I mixed up everything in my math and in my translation to English. Anyway. My question was trivial ... sorry Sorry about the noise.

Comment: Now that you have asked this, we may be  curious whether there exists a domain $A$ with some non-invertible element that is Not divisible by an irreducible element. It is not hard to check that in a Noetherian domain every non-invertible element is a product of several irreducible elements ( uniqueness is equivalent to UFD).  So the example should be searched among $A$ not Noetherian.